# ComboBox that hides records based on criteria

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, combobox

I am making a system that agendizes meetings. Each meeting can have up to three items agendized.

I want to use a combobox to select the meeting date because these meetings are held relatively sporadically.

I have a one column table for the meeting dates. I'm working with highly confidential information, so I am masking to the bare minimum.

It's structured like:
Meeting Date
[Date (short date format)]

In the agenda item table, there is a Meeting Date combobox that is fed by the Meeting Date table. This works as expected, users click in the combobox and dates appear in the list.

I want to make two improvements.

Improvement 1:
When the date is in the past from the meeting date database, it is removed from the combobox selection. (I'm okay if the date is just deleted from the meeting date database since the dates will be stored in the agenda item database, but I would prefer to hide in case I need to refer back for reporting).

Improvement 2:
If there are three items agendized for the date (i.e., the date exists three times in the agenda item table - meeting date column), the date is not selectable (hidden/disabled) in the combobox. This way if we cancel an item, the date reappears in the list.

I would provide code, but I don't know where to start. I considered a query for the count part, but I don't know how to link that back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

1. only list dates that are on or after current date?
2. only select dates that don't already have 3 agenda items?

Need to build an aggregate query that counts agenda items and use that query in a LEFT JOIN to Meetings table.

```
SELECT * FROM Meetings LEFT JOIN (SELECT MeetingDate, Count(*) AS Cnt FROM AgendaItems GROUP BY MeetingDate) AS C
ON Meetings.MeetingDate=C.MeetingDate
WHERE MeetingDate>Date() AND Nz(Cnt,0)<3;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can figure this out. There are no spaces in my table names/headers. The initial post was just illustrative.

Comment: I think I'm using this wrong. I modified the code to use the database's actual table names and headers, then pasted into the Field: section of the query. I'm 100% certain I did the wrong thing. I receive the error: "The syntax of the subquery in this expression is incorrect. Check the subquery's syntax and enclose the subquery in parentheses."

Comment: No, nested query does not go in Field. Switch query builder to SQLView and type or copy/paste one of the SQL statements. Change table and/or field names as needed. Then switch to Design view.

Comment: I went with the second choice because I understand it (mostly). I think I have an issue because the header in the Meetings database has the same name as the header in the AgendaItems database. Could this cause a conflict? I get all dates in the future as expected if I do just:

SELECT * FROM Meetings 
WHERE MeetingDate > Date(); 

If I tack on the rest of the query, though, I get blank results.

Comment: Addendum, it works if the count is nonzero. I added one of the dates into the form and now I get results. Is there a way to not exclude zero count results?

Comment: Okay, see revised answer. I should have done some testing because count factor complicated what is normally fairly simple query.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing this for me. It works like a charm.